# Receive index of current comparison in a linq statement

Tags: linq, lambda

```
til.First(t => ViewModel.StringValue.CompareTo(t.StringValue) <= 0).StringValue;
```

Is it posible to get the index value of t at the time of comparing so that one can use it in another array to access data to be used in the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not directly with `First` but with a Select /  First, yes (you'll get an anonymous object in that sample)

```
var res = til.Select((x, index) => new {
            x.StringValue,
            index
          })
             .First(t => ViewModel.StringValue.CompareTo(t.StringValue)<= 0);
```

so index would be

```
res.index
```

and strValue would be

```
res.StrValue
```

This would give you an anonymous object, with a `StringValue`  and an `index` property

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add an intermediary `.Select()` which brings an anonymous type object containing both the current `t` object, as well as it's index:

```
til
  .Select((t, index) => new {t, index})
    // x.index is available on the next line
  .First(x => ViewModel.StringValue.CompareTo(x.t.StringValue) <= 0)
  .t.StringValue;
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus OP says he needs to *"get the index value of t at the time of comparing"*, so I assumed having the index available inside the `.First()` lambda will do.

Comment: Yup, but if you do directly `t.StringValue` after the call on `.First(xxxx)`, you won't get it.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus again, I assume OP needs the index only inside the call to `.First`, perhaps to log it or perform additional look-ups with it.